# Run a animation on a canvas in streamlit.io?

Tags: tkinter, canvas, streamlit

I have a local application that runs an animation on a canvas in tkinter. Would it be possible to run such a program in the cloud with streamlit.io and show the animation on the client side? If not, are there comparable cloud services where thi could work?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a full project. On this website we really don't want to design whole applications. This website is for narrow questions. If you design the program and have trouble with something particular ask us.

Comment: Its an existing animation library that works fine for simple 2d animations, as mentioned it runs on a canvas in tkinter. The issue is to display the animations in Streamlit.io , would this be possble?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't think it's even possible to animate things properly in tkinter. I am sure that there are better GUI frameworks out there. But even if you do wish to make a animation: it won't look smooth, because tkinter is just made for simple GUIs.

Anyways, maybe this can help:

```py
import tkinter
import time
 
# width of the animation window
animation_window_width=800
# height of the animation window
animation_window_height=600
# initial x position of the ball
animation_ball_start_xpos = 50
# initial y position of the ball
animation_ball_start_ypos = 50
# radius of the ball
animation_ball_radius = 30
# the pixel movement of ball for each iteration
animation_ball_min_movement = 5
# delay between successive frames in seconds
animation_refresh_seconds = 0.01
 
# The main window of the animation
def create_animation_window():
  window = tkinter.Tk()
  window.title("Tkinter Animation Demo")
  # Uses python 3.6+ string interpolation
  window.geometry(f'{animation_window_width}x{animation_window_height}')
  return window
 
# Create a canvas for animation and add it to main window
def create_animation_canvas(window):
  canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window)
  canvas.configure(bg="black")
  canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
  return canvas
 
# Create and animate ball in an infinite loop
def animate_ball(window, canvas,xinc,yinc):
  ball = canvas.create_oval(animation_ball_start_xpos-animation_ball_radius,
            animation_ball_start_ypos-animation_ball_radius,
            animation_ball_start_xpos+animation_ball_radius,
            animation_ball_start_ypos+animation_ball_radius,
            fill="blue", outline="white", width=4)
  while True:
    canvas.move(ball,xinc,yinc)
    window.update()
    time.sleep(animation_refresh_seconds)
    ball_pos = canvas.coords(ball)
    # unpack array to variables
    xl,yl,xr,yr = ball_pos
    if xl < abs(xinc) or xr > animation_window_width-abs(xinc):
      xinc = -xinc
    if yl < abs(yinc) or yr > animation_window_height-abs(yinc):
      yinc = -yinc
 
# The actual execution starts here
animation_window = create_animation_window()
animation_canvas = create_animation_canvas(animation_window)
animate_ball(animation_window,animation_canvas, animation_ball_min_movement, animation_ball_min_movement)
```

Also see this page for information: https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/python/how-to-create-canvas-animation-using-tkinter.html

A upvote or mark as answer would be really helpful <3 Thanks